# Increase speed using only one loop?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop

Is there a way to rewrite this code using only one loop to increase the speed while the input is very large numbers?

The code is used to count how many integers in a list are greater than all integers to the right of it.

```
count = 0
for i,x in enumerate(items):
    d = True
    for y in items[i+1:]:
        if x <= y:
            d = False
    if d:
        count = count+1        
return count
```

Comment: How long is the list expected to be? 100 items, 10.000 or even millions of items?

Comment: Not really an answer to the question but you could make your second loop faster if you break it when you find a "false " value.

Comment: @chepner I understood the question as counting how many elements are greater that the elements to their right side; in a ascending-sorted list no element satisfies that condition (or maybe just the last one), but in a descending-sorted list every element satisfies that condition. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 4):

The current value is larger than all the ones to the right if and only it is larger than the maximum one.

This code implements the above idea by iterating from right to left:

```
count = 0
max = None
for val in items[::-1]:
    if max is None or val > max:
        max = val
        count += 1
return count
```

Comment: The count can never be higher than 1 if you are really interested in `>`, not `>=`. In the list `[5, 5, 5]`, only the rightmost `5` will contribute to the count. The function returns 0 for empty inputs, 1 for non-empty inputs, so only the length, not the the actual contents, is needed.

Comment: @chepner: It can be greater than 1, for example in this case: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -- every number is larger than all the ones to the right.

Comment: @qwertyman your proposal is quite good; I did an comparison in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960524/9225671)

Answer (score 2):

I timed some options to compare them:

The code from the question:

```
def f1(item_list):
    count = 0

    for i, x in enumerate(item_list):
        d = True
        for y in item_list[i+1:]:
            if x <= y:
                d = False
        if d:
            count = count+1

    return count
```

The code from [this answer from `qwertyman`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959925/9225671):

```
def f2(item_list):
    max_elem = None
    count = 0

    for val in item_list[::-1]:
        if max_elem is None or val > max_elem:
            max_elem = val
            count += 1

    return count
```

My improved version (just used `reversed()` instead of `[::-1]`):

```
def f3(item_list):
    max_elem = None
    count = 0

    for val in reversed(item_list):
        if max_elem is None or max_elem < val:
            max_elem = val
            count += 1

    return count
```

The comparison code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_list = [f1, f2, f3]
    print('{:>8s} {:15s} {:>10s} {:>10s} {:>10s}'.format(
        'n', 'items', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'))

    for n in (100, 1000, 5000):
        items_1 = [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(n)]
        items_2 = list(sorted(items_1))
        items_3 = list(sorted(items_1, reverse=True))

        for label, items in [
            ('random', items_1),
            ('sorted', items_2),
            ('sorted-reverse', items_3),
        ]:
            # assure that all functions return the same result
            assert len(set([func(items) for func in func_list])) == 1

            t_list = []
            for func in func_list:
                t_list.append(
                    timeit.timeit(
                        'func(items)',
                        'from __main__ import func, items',
                        number=100))
            print('{:8d} {:15s} {:10.6f} {:10.6f} {:10.6f}'.format(
                n, label, *t_list))
```

The results (using `Python 3.6` on `Ubuntu 18.04`):

```
       n items                   f1         f2         f3
     100 random            0.016022   0.000348   0.000370
     100 sorted            0.015840   0.000339   0.000326
     100 sorted-reverse    0.014122   0.000572   0.000505
    1000 random            1.502731   0.003212   0.003077
    1000 sorted            1.496299   0.003332   0.003089
    1000 sorted-reverse    1.256896   0.005412   0.005196
    5000 random           36.812474   0.015695   0.014762
    5000 sorted           36.902378   0.015983   0.015067
    5000 sorted-reverse   31.218129   0.019741   0.018419
```

Clearly, the proposal by `qwertyman` is orders of magnitude faster than the original code, and it can be sped up a little bit by using `reversed()` (obviously, for more speed one could use another language instead of Python).